# Nested divs inside iframe selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

Im trying to use selenium with python to execute javascript on the id callled g-recaptcha-response.
[Picture of HTML with div im targeting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70VNE.png)

But i'm getting this error saying Message: no such element: Unable to locate element. Here is the script that I have so far

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://testform2020.bss.design")

#open up where the id is located 
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn-block').click()
#remove overlay
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('body > div:nth-child(6)').style.display = 'none'")
#target the frame
iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[0])
driver.switch_to.default_content()
time.sleep(3)
container = driver.find_element_by_name('g-recaptcha-response')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", container)
```

Comment: Instead of using time.sleep, try ```from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'someid')))```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem was I had driver.switch_to.default_content() which was switching back to the main content but i needed to go further down the page

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had driver.switch_to.default_content() which was switching back to the main content but i needed to go further down the page